# Pairing elements of lists together

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm creating a function in Scheme called pair-elements with the following specifications. It takes one list of multiple sublists, each of which must have just two elements (I'm not checking for this right now though). It returns a list of two sublists, one with the first element of every one of the given sublists and the other with the second element of them. Here's an example of what it should do:

>(pair-elements '((a b)(c d)(e f)))
((a c e) (b d f))

Here's what I have so far. I've been able to successfully create the first sublist with this code:

```
(define (pair-elements x)
    (if (null? x)
    null
    (cons (caar x) (pair-elements (cdr x)))))
```

When tested, this is the result:
>(pair-elements '((a b)(c d)(e f)))
(a c e)

Its a step in the right direction, but I can't figure out how to do the second part AND put them both into a list. All of my attempts have resulted in very ugly outputs. For example, one of my attempts with:

```
(cons (cons (caar x) (pair-elements (cdr x))) (cons (cdar x) (pair-elements (cdr x))))))
```

Gets the output ((a (c (e) (f)) (d) (e) (f)) (b) (c (e) (f)) (d) (e) (f)), which is obviously way off.

Can anyone help me finish this function? I'm a newbie at Scheme, and I definitely need to know how to do something like this. Making lists of sublists is something I'm especially struggling with.

Comment: My immediate thought on reading your question is that your initial code is not tail recursive, and this is scheme code, where tail calls will be optimized.  Try writing a `pair-elements-aux` that takes three arguments so you can write  `(pair-elements-aux '((a b)(c d)(e f)) null null)` and use the additional two arguments as your result sublists, which will allow you to build your final result directly at the bottom of your recursion using `list` and `reverse`.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, I might use that if I need to. But I'm almost certain that there's a far simpler solution that doesn't need tail recursion or an auxiliary function.

Comment: @anomie-p the fact that is not tail recursive is not important, what matters is that there are built-in procedures that greatly simplify the solution.

Comment: @Bob indeed there's a simpler solution, if we just use the built-in procedures that allow us to manipulate lists - using auxiliary functions is ok, in fact is encouraged.

Comment: @Bob I was assuming you wanted a recursive solution based on the code given in your question. The solution given using `map` is certainly simpler than using recursion here, but if you are going to use recursion, I think tail calls are the way to go, due to the language support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation is basically reinventing the wheel - this will be a lot easier if you use the built-in procedure [`map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29), which does what you want; you just have to pass as a parameter the procedure that you want to apply on each element of the input list (`first` and `second` in this case):

```
(define (pair-elements lst)
  (list                 ; create a new list with the two sublists
   (map first lst)      ; sublist of first elements of input list
   (map second lst)))   ; sublist of second elements of input list
```

We can go even further, and use the fact that `map` can receive multiple lists as input:

```
(define (pair-elements lst) ; process input list element-wise on each
  (apply map list lst))     ; sublist and create a list with them
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(pair-elements '((a b) (c d) (e f)))
=> '((a c e) (b d f))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much! I didn't know map could be implemented so easily.